# Why isn't Jest applying my timeout when I use jest.setTimeout()?

Tags: jestjs

I know I can [use `jest.setTimeout()` to set a custom timeout for a test](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout). I'm doing this below. `MINUTE` has the value `60 * 1000`.

Why isn't Jest applying my timeout?

```
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      13 |
      14 | describe(`integration with API provider`, () => {
    > 15 |   it(`works`, async () => {
         |   ^
      16 |     // Just in case network is slow.
      17 |     jest.setTimeout(1 * MINUTE);
```

Comment: _"This only affects **the test file** from which this function is called."_ - you're expected to call it from the file, not the test. Jest sets the timeout _before_ calling the function, you can't change it from inside. For a single test's timeout, you can pass a third argument to `it`/`test`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you want to add this - in particular the 'for a single tests timeout' part - as an answer?

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68811529/3001761.

Comment: Hah apparently I answered this before too . Feel free to mark as a dupe if you like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you've seen (and despite what's claimed elsewhere on SO), you *cannot* change a single test's timeout by calling `jest.setTimeout` from inside it. Note that the docs you quote state (emphasis mine):

> This only affects **the test file** from which this function is called.

It's intended to be used at test *discovery* time, not *execution* time, to set the timeout for a given context. The timeout is set before the test callback is invoked, you can't change it once the test actually starts.

For a single test you can set the timeout by passing a third argument to [the `test`/`it` function](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout) (or the various helpers defined on it), for example:

```js
it("has a description", () => {
  // ...
}, 60_000);
```

Comment: Link edit 'passing a third argument to the test/it function' was to describe what is being linked (the link demonstrates passing a third argument). Obviously you don't seem to like the change so I've left it as is.

Comment: I've [fixed the jest docs to make them clearer](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/12809)